# How to test multiple versions of cast receiver app

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Is there any way to test multiple versions of cast receiver app in staging? Right now, there is only two environments staging and production which supports two versions of the receiver app but what if multiple versions are needed within staging environment like one for devs and one for QA. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Cast SDK Developer Console you can add as many receiver application (versions) as you want. You can add an app versions for development, QA, staging, and production, and host these versions at different locations. You will get a different ID for each version, which you need to integrate in your sender app versions for development/QA/staging/production.

Note that 'publish' for a receiver application in the Google Cast SDK Developer Console just means that the receiver app is allowed to run on any chromecast device, not only the devices registered under the same account in the developer console.